# android send string to a service running in another process

Tags: android, service, ipc

I'm using [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/) tutorial to help me use a service that will always run in the background even if the application itself is in the background, and I want to be able to transfer strings between My main process and the service.
The thing is, I see all over the place that marshaling strings is supposed to be very easy, but for more complex stuff one needs AIDL.
Since I only want to send string messages, I figured there must be a very easy way to do this, but I can't find it..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a *very* hackish solution and very not OOP-like, but it's what I ended up doing, so I'm putting it here if anyone ever finds the needs for a simple, not very elegant (but working) solution.

I'm using `sendBroadcast` and `broadcastReceiver` to communicate between the service and the application.
The problem is that sending intents cross process for some reason removes all the extras, so I used `SharedPrefences` instead.

this is the (singleton) class I use in order to publish and subscribe to such string messaging.

The Visitor interface

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    public void visit(T element);
}
```

The publish subscriber interface:

```
public interface IPulishSubscribe {
    /**
     * Publish a new string message
     * 
     * @param key The key to publish under
     * @param text The message's content
     */
    public void publish(String key, String text);

    /**
     * Subscribe to a message
     * 
     * @param key The key to subscribe to
     * @param visitor The visitor to handle the message when received
     */
    public void subscribe(final String key, final Visitor<String> visitor);
}
```

The implementation

```
public class PublishSubscriber implements IPulishSubscribe {
    private static IPulishSubscribe         _instance       = new PublishSubscriber();
    private static Context                  _context;
    // key -> handler, isn't of much use ATM, but you may need it for removals...
    private Map<String, BroadcastReceiver>  _subscribers    = new HashMap<String, BroadcastReceiver>();
    private PublishSubscriber() {
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public static IPulishSubscribe getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(String key, String text) {
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, text);
        editor.commit();
        _context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(key));
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void subscribe(final String key, final Visitor<String> visitor) {
        BroadcastReceiver newSubscriber = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
                String data = mPrefs.getString(key, null);
                if (visitor != null) {
                    visitor.visit(data);
                }
            }
        };
        _context.registerReceiver(newSubscriber, new IntentFilter(key));
        _subscribers.put(key, newSubscriber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a intent service is the way to go.
Howto create a intent service is explained [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score -1):

@Gal I like your answer. I dont know how fast it is but I hope it gets your job done.

I have been also confronting this problem. My first try was Messenger api, as demonstrated in Service documentation. It works but is rather limiting as to what you can send. You have to use a Bundle to send Strings.

```
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    Bundle data = new Bundle(1); // size of Bundle array

    data.putString("anything");
    messenger.send(msg);
```

There are some nuances about reusing Message and Bundle objects in case you dont want to constantly create new objects.

I then tried AIDL in order to do interprocess communications easier. But after building the api, I clicked send send send and saw nothing.

The final way I tried was with files. Simple create a file, write to it and read from it on the other end. Sounds easy, but getting working properly is hard. Then you must understanding that the file will just grow and grow in size.

```
class Service_ extends Service
{
    @Override protected void onCreate
    {
         new FileObserver("/sdcard/IFILE")
         {
              @Override public void onEvent(int event,String path)
               {
                 if(event == MODIFY){} // Client sent message
               }
         }
    }
}

class Client extends ServiceConnection
{
  java.io.RandomAccessFile serviceWriter = new java.io.RandomAccessFile("/sdcard/IFILE");
}
```

Problem I have been facing is FileObserver seems to always be notified of file modification, yet my service fails to read the INIT instruction, which the client sents once so that the service can create the backing Console activity.

another thing is that Android is essentially Linux. Linux has raw methods for sending messages and file handle between processes. Atleast in the C api.